# For loop for printing letters

Tags: java

```
public class LetterPrint {
    int totalLines;
    int consecLines;
    int timesPrintedinLine;
    int linesPrinted;
    char currentChar;
    LetterPrint(int totalLines, int consecLines){
        this.totalLines = totalLines;
        this.consecLines = consecLines;
    }
    void beginPrinting(){
        for(timesPrintedinLine = 0; linesPrinted<=totalLines; timesPrintedinLine++)
        {
            Print();
        }
    }
    public char correctChar(){
        if(timesPrintedinLine/(consecLines*4) == 1)
            return currentChar = 'A';
        else 
            return currentChar = 'B';

    }
    void Print(){
        if (timesPrintedinLine%5 !=0)
            System.out.print(correctChar());
        else{
            System.out.println();
            linesPrinted = timesPrintedinLine/4;
        }

    }
}
```

Can anyone help me see why, when created with "LetterPrint letterPrinter = new LetterPrint(6,1);" this object is printing

```
BBBA
AABB
BBBB
BBBB
BBBB
BBBB
```

rather than

```
AAAA
BBBB
AAAA
BBBB
AAAA
BBBB
```

I appreciate anyone who can clear this up for me.

Comment: what are the initial values?

Comment: @njzk2 `new LetterPrint(6, 1);`

Comment: By the way, I don't see any point to keep `int timesPrintedinLine; int linesPrinted; char currentChar;` as object fields. How comes that they are not local variables?

Comment: 6 for totalLines, 1 for consecLines.

Comment: The parameters respond to 6 totalLines, 1 conescLines - (Whoops, got ninja'd by the author.)

Comment: I got ninja'd by Regent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since the original code isn't "the best one", I have rewritten it:

```
public class LetterPrint
{
    private final static int charsInLine = 4;

    private final int totalLines;
    private final int consecLines;

    public LetterPrint(int totalLines, int consecLines)
    {
        this.totalLines = totalLines;
        this.consecLines = consecLines;
    }

    public void beginPrinting()
    {
        for (int lineNumber = 0; lineNumber < totalLines; lineNumber++)
        {
            char currentChar = getChar(lineNumber);
            for (int charNumber = 0; charNumber < charsInLine; charNumber++)
            {
                System.out.print(currentChar);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    private char getChar(int lineNumber)
    {
        if ((lineNumber / consecLines) % 2 == 0)
        {
            return 'A';
        }
        return 'B';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Step through each process. `timesPrintedInLine` is first 0, so in `Print()` it will print a new line. When `timesPrintedInLine` is 1, 1 is not a multiple of 5, so the `System.out.print` will print the `char` returned from `correctChar()` in `Print()`; because 1/(1*4) does not equal 1, `B` is printed. Same happens for 2 and 3.

When `timesPrintedInLine` is 4, we go to `correctChar()` again; `A` is printed this time.

`timesPrintedInLine` now becomes 5, so a new line is printed, and `linesPrinted` is now equal to 5/4, or 1.

For `timesPrintedInLine` = 6 and 7, `A` is printed since 6/4 and 7/4 equal 1.

From this point on, `timesPrintedInLine` will always be greater than 7. Subsequently, `timesPrintedInLine`/(1*4) can never equal 1, so that is why `B` is always printed (except for when `timesPrintedInLine` is a multiple of 5; in this case a new line is printed and `linesPrinted` equals `timesPrintedInLine`/4).

The problem is coming from your `if` statement, so change it to this:

```
if(timesPrintedinLine/(consecLines*5) % 2 == 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

first, timesPrintedinLine and linesPrinted for conventions and best practices need to be declared as local variables.
Second try to not call to often the System.out

Now the correct code can be this:

```
public class LetterPrint {
   private static final int CHARS_BY_CONSLINES = 4; 

   private int totalLines;
   private int consecLines;

   LetterPrint(int totalLines, int consecLines){
       this.totalLines = totalLines;
       this.consecLines = consecLines;
   }

   void beginPrinting(){
       String text;
       for(int rows = 0; rows < totalLines; rows++){
           text = "";
           for (int cols = 0; cols < consecLines*CHARS_BY_CONSLINES; cols++) {
               text += printChar(rows);
           }
           System.out.println(text);
       }
   } 

   void printChar(int row){
       if (row%2==0)
           return "A";
       else
           return "B"
   }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Corrected your code to the maximum possible extent.

```
public class LetterPrint {
    int totalLines;
    int consecLines;
    int timesPrintedinLine;
    int linesPrinted;
    char currentChar;
    LetterPrint(int totalLines, int consecLines){
        this.totalLines = totalLines;
        this.consecLines = consecLines;
    }
    void beginPrinting(){
        for(timesPrintedinLine = 1; linesPrinted<=totalLines; timesPrintedinLine++)
        {
            Print();
        }
    }
    public char correctChar(){
        if((timesPrintedinLine/(consecLines*4+1)) %2  == 0)
            return currentChar = 'A';
        else 
            return currentChar = 'B';

    }
    void Print(){
        if (timesPrintedinLine%5 !=0)
            System.out.print(correctChar());
        else{
            System.out.println();
            linesPrinted = timesPrintedinLine/4;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String ar[])
    {
     LetterPrint LETTERPRINTER = new LetterPrint(6,1);
     LETTERPRINTER.beginPrinting();
    }
}
```

The output is as expected.

```
AAAA
BBBB
AAAA
BBBB
AAAA
BBBB
```

The change made are

1. The `for` loop starts from `1` to avoid the printing of the first blank line.
2. The condition in the function `correctChar` has been changed to accommodate subsequent changes. (Yours was restricted to the first iteration)

If you want explanation, please ask.