# jQuery Counter with Max and Min Value

Tags: jquery, counter

I'm building a counter that should increment up to a *maxValue* and decrement no further than *0* when I mousedown. I also have an option to reset the counter to it's initial value: *0*. Also, if the maxValue is an *even number* it should count up to that number. However, if the maxValue is an *odd number*, it should count up to number-1.

The counter seems to be work fine. But sometimes it tends to stay stuck between two values. I'm pretty sure that this occurs when I mousedown on one of the buttons and then immediately mousedown on the other. Is there a way to prevent that from happening?  I also wanted to know if my code is correct if if there is a simpler approach to this (perhaps with loops)?

Anyway here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var maxValue = 3;
var count = 0;
// intervals used to regulate how fast the value will change on mousedown
var upInterval;
var downInterval;

$('#counter').html("<p>" + parseInt(count) + "</p>");

$('#up').mousedown(function(){
 // if the maxValue is an even number
 if(maxValue % 2 == 0) {
    upInterval = setInterval(function(){
        if(count < maxValue) {
            count++;
            $('#counter').html("<p>" + parseInt(count) + "</p>");
        }
    },180);
  }
// if it's an odd number, subtract one
 else {
    upInterval = setInterval(function(){
        if(count < maxValue-1) {
            count++;
            $('#counter').html("<p>" + parseInt(count) + "</p>");
        }
    },180);
 }
}).mouseup(function() {
    clearInterval(upInterval);       
}); 

$('#down').mousedown(function(){
    downInterval = setInterval(function(){
        if(count > 0) {
            count--;
            $('#counter').html("<p>" + parseInt(count) + "</p>");
        }
    },180);
}).mouseup(function() {
    clearInterval(downInterval);    
});

    $('#reset').click(function(){
        count = 0;
        $('#counter').html("<p>" + parseInt(count) + "</p>");
    });

});
```

Keep in mind that the intervals are there to regulate how fast the number should change when I mousedown and to stop it from incrementing or decrementing.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q5hoegcr/)

Thanks!

Comment: Why not simply increment by *even* numbers (2)?

Comment: I need it to increment by all numbers up to the maxValue if it's even, same goes for the odd except the maxValue should be interpreted as one less. Ex: if maxValue = 13, then it would count up to 12 (1,2,3,4...12). If I understand you correctly, then it would only count up by even numbers, so (2,4,6...) which is not what I want.

Comment: Ohh I've got it. Sec to set up an example.

Comment: In the even number case you would divide by 2 while storing/returning.

Comment: ehm no - he doesnt. Please note the variable above the functions

Comment: "mousedown" triggers exactly one time - when you press the mousebutton. As soon as you stop holding it, the interval gets cleared (not a big problem here if you dont have tremors). But please show us your solution...

Comment: @Ferret well, indeed, something goes wrong in my fiddle and in my mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***[jsBin demo (advanced use-case)](http://jsbin.com/nobigo/3/edit)***

in the demo above I've created an use-case where you can handle multiple elements. It also has **a better UX** cause it uses a **setTimeout** (instead of interval) which will gradually increase the counting speed as long as you hold it.

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/pocici/3/edit?html,js,output)***

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var $counter = $("#counter p"), // Get the 'p' element
      max = 10,
      c   = 0,
      up  = true, // boolean // This will keep track of the clicked up/dn button
      itv; 

  function incDec(){
    c = up ? ++c : --c; // value of `up` is true? increment, else: decrement
    c = Math.min(Math.max(c, 0), max); // dididababaduuuu!
    $counter.text(c);                  // Set current `c` into element
  }

  $('#up, #down').on("mousedown", function(e){   
    up = this.id==="up";           // set to true if button in "up"; else: false
    incDec();                      // Trigger on sligle click
    clearInterval(itv);            // Clear some ongoing intervals
    itv=setInterval(incDec, 180);  // Do every 180 untill..
  }).on("mouseup mouseleave", function(){        //      ..mouseup or mouseleave
    clearInterval(itv); 
  });


  $('#reset').click(function(){
    c = 0;              // Reset to 0
    $counter.text(c);   // Show that "0"           
  }).click();           // Trigger a reset click on DOM ready

});
```

Comment: And one thing about code itself: I suggest to pass `up` as argument to function `incDec`. "Global" variable in this case is not good style, that's for sure. [This example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509890/for-loop-for-printing-letters/27510568) is what it can end up with this.

Comment: @Regent well, that's not true in this case. In the first place you can wrap the whole code inside an IIFE. In he second place to make the code reusable for more counters (in the case of a plugin) you would not use `#`...in the first place! :)

Comment: I have tried both `mouseleave` and `mouseout`, but something went wrong. I can't repeat it now. The only way when counter is going on (being out of element, if it can be called "out") is when you select all text and are moving its in page. But I doubt it's really the problem which needs to be fixed.

Comment: Using `incDec(this.id==="up");` and `function incDec(up) {` is reusable and safe (you can't call function not setting value for `up`. Well, in JS you can, but it will be treated as `false` in this situation).

Comment: @Regent I clearly don't understand what you're talking here about. The code in this exact case is bulletproof (clearly it can be optimized...) but as you can see there's not a single issue. `up` is defined as `true`. And as such it will be never `undefined, null` or else. (thanks in any case for sharing your concerns)

Answer (score 0):

Im only able to reproduce the "stuck" you described, if the "mouseup" doesnt happen on the element itself (e.g. moving the cursor out while you press the mouse).
So this solved it for me:

```
$('#up').mousedown(function(){
    $(window).mouseup(function() {
        clearInterval(upInterval);       
    });

  // if the maxValue is an even number
  ....
});
// and so on
```

Comment: Adding event handler inside another event handler is nearly always very bad idea.